# Fastest way to escape a String in JavaME

Tags: java, string, java-me, escaping

I have a method that looks like this:

```
public static String escape(String text)
{
   String r = replace(text, "\\", "\\\\");
   r = replace(r, "\r", "\\r");
   r = replace(r, "\b", "\\b");
   r = replace(r, "\t", "\\t");
   r = replace(r, "\n", "\\n");
   r = replace(r, "\f", "\\f");
   return r;
}
```

Is there a faster, less brutal way to do this and if so what would that way look like?

Note that this is J2ME, so no Apache commons, and no regex.

Comment: This looks like C#, but please specify what language you are referring to.

Comment: This method will not do what you want. You mix up the regular expressions, and you mix up the variable names you use. I suggest you get it *working* before you get it *fast*.

Comment: That is a little buggy. For instance `\\r` becomes `\r` becomes CR.

Comment: Ooops, oops, oops. I asked the wrong question. I've updated my code.

Comment: You still have a bug.  The first replace statement (\\ -> \\\\\) has no effect.

Comment: Oh yes.. you mean because of the following line ignoring r.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like below.  You'll have to benchmark it for your own target devices to make sure, but I think it will certainly be faster since you are not creating a new String object for every replace.  And, it will be better from a creating garbage on the heap standpoint, which may or may not help with heap fragmentation.

```
public static String escape(String text) { 
    if(text == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int numChars = text.length();
    char ch;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < numChars; i++) {
        ch = text.charAt(i);

        switch(ch) {
            case '\\':  { sb.append("\\\\"); break; }
            case '\r':  { sb.append("\\r"); break; }
            case '\b':  { sb.append("\\b"); break; }
            case '\t':  { sb.append("\\t"); break; }
            case '\n':  { sb.append("\\n"); break; }
            case '\f':  { sb.append("\\f"); break; }
            default: {
                sb.append(ch);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean "fast" for the developer or performance? If it's the latter, then use a char array & do it all yourself. It will be much faster since you can do it in one pass.

Comment: Fast for the developer would be to keep the method I have. I was hoping for a fast-performing alternative that I could measure a difference with.

Answer (score 1):

Once it works (comment noted above), the simplest way to speed it up is to perform the replacements using a [StringBuffer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).

*But*, have you measured this ? Is it a bottleneck ? I would suggest you do this before expending energy on optimisations.

Answer (score -3):

hm can't you just use

```
public static String escape(String text)
{
   String r = replace(text, "\", "\\");
   return r;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that "\n" doesn't contain a '\' to find.

Comment: I don't get it. 
Then the r = replace(r, "\n", "\\n"); is not right?

Comment: '\n' is a carriage return character; a single character. A '\' is a backslash; also a single character. I want to replace carriage returns with a backslash followed by a 'n'.

Comment: @izb, why did you accept this answer?  Fostah's answer is probably the best you're going to get, and you *know* this one's wrong.